# Android Customised ListView and ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Currently, I have a default listview displaying names from an `Arraylist` JavaClassName. I wished to implement an imageview into the listview so I have read and tried methods from these 2 links:
[Android Custom Listview with Image and Text using ArrayAdapter](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)
[Android Custom ListView with Images and Text – Example](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

I have problems converting from their `String[]` and `Integer[]` in their respective `CustomList` classes into my own `ArrayList` as the image and name are stored in that `Arraylist`. My `ArrayList` consist of other data as well but I only need to get data to show in the customised `ListView`.

Edits/Add on:

```
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

I have followed closely to one of the links provided to create a customAdapter. And this is what I have in the MainActivity

```
final ArrayList<JavaClassName> arrayListName = new ArrayList<JavaClassName>();
arrayListName.add(new JavaClassName(R.drawable.icon1, "name", "info", "info", "info"));
arrayListName.add(new JavaClassName(R.drawable.icon2, "name", "info", "info", "info"));

final ArrayList<String> itemName = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<arrayListName.size(); i++){
        String name = arrayListName.get(i).getName().toString();
        itemName.add(name);
    };

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemName);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I fit the String[] and Integer[] from the CustomAdapter class into the CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemName);?

Comment: Care to share your code and properly explain what's happening?

Comment: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListName);`
this is my current adapter. the given 2 links uses this adapater which passes 2 array: `CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);`
So how can I make changes to obtain the image and name from my arraylist into the customListAdapter without making another 2 arrays?

Comment: You will have to create custom adapter that accepts the collections that you have created for populating the data in the list, in order to make custom listview. For more on this, provide the code in the question, so that one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyk_ht8z6IA

From what I can tell, I suggest you should create your own adapter. I not sure about arraylist as most of the time I only used arrays.

Comment: Yes, I did create my own adapter but I am unsure of how to change to fit the arraylist. If I were to use arrays, I have another 4-5 data which means I have to create multiple arrays. The purpose of me doing an arraylist is because my ListView once clicked, will be intented to another page which displays multiple data from the arrayList

Answer (score 0):

> Convert **`ArrayList to Array`**

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
// add stuff here
String[] namesArr = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your custom adapter class inherits from ArrayAdapter, I presume. According to the docs, the resource that you provide to the constructor (2nd argument, `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in your case) should be a layout containing a `TextView` -

[image]

Since you have a more complex layout than just a `TextView`, you should extend the `BaseAdapter` class instead. Then,

1. Create your own ArrayList(s) to manage your data (An `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` in your case).
2. Provide add, remove and other similar methods to manage your lists.
3. Override the `getView` method to inflate your custom layout to set the texts and image as per your requirements.